# SQL oracle пересчет сумм в неотрицательные

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть договор и даты с суммами начислений.
Начисления могут быть с плюсом и минусом, например:

```
contract_id = 1 
01.01.2024 100₽
02.01.2024 500₽
03.01.2024 300₽ 
04.01.2024 -700₽ 
05.01.2024 -50₽ 
06.01.2024 50₽ 
07.01.2024 -30₽ 
08.01.2024 100₽
```

Мне нужно написать sql запрос select, который рассчитает результат таким образом, чтобы вместо отрицательных значений в списке начислений уменьшились ближайшие предыдущие положительные значения, чтобы все значения начислений были неотрицательными, как будто не было отрицательных начислений, а положительные были меньше, то есть:

```
contract_id = 1
01.01.2024 100₽ 
02.01.2024 50₽
03.01.2024 0₽ 
04.01.2024 0₽ 
05.01.2024 0₽ 
06.01.2024 20₽
07.01.2024 0₽
08.01.2024 100₽
```

Каким запросом это можно сделать?

Comment: В общем случае никак. Достаточно просто представить случай, когда общая сумма отрицательна...

Comment: Предположим, что общая сумма не бывает отрицательной.

Comment: Никакой constraint не может обеспечить выполнение этого условия - значит, такая ситуация не просто возможна, но и обязательно возникнет.

Comment: @Akina - однако банки до сих пор как-то успешно справлялись с попытками клиентов снять со своего счёта больше, чем они туда положили :-)  к данной задаче эта сложность отношения не имеет, т.к. автор спрашивает про запрос к DWH, а "выполнение этого условия" гарантируется системой-источником (OLTP), ну или просто триггером на этой таблице, который гарантирует невыход в минус при апдейте этой таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала вычисляете нарастающий итог, потом ищете в нём "будущий минимум":

Подготовка таблицы

```
create table sums (contract_id number, dt date, amount number);

insert into sums (contract_id, dt, amount)
    select 1 as contract_id, date'2024-01-01' as dt,  100 as amount from dual union all
    select 1 as contract_id, date'2024-01-02' as dt,  500 as amount from dual union all
    select 1 as contract_id, date'2024-01-03' as dt,  300 as amount from dual union all
    select 1 as contract_id, date'2024-01-04' as dt, -700 as amount from dual union all
    select 1 as contract_id, date'2024-01-05' as dt,  -50 as amount from dual union all
    select 1 as contract_id, date'2024-01-06' as dt,   50 as amount from dual union all
    select 1 as contract_id, date'2024-01-07' as dt,  -30 as amount from dual union all
    select 1 as contract_id, date'2024-01-08' as dt,  100 as amount from dual;
```

Запрос

```
select
    contract_id,
    dt,
    amount,
    greatest(0, min(acc) over (partition by contract_id order by dt desc) - acc + amount)
        as positive_amount
from
    (
        select
            contract_id,
            dt,
            amount,
            sum(amount) over (partition by contract_id order by dt) as acc
        from
            sums
    )
order by
    contract_id,
    dt
```

| CONTRACT_ID | DT | AMOUNT | POSITIVE_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2024 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 02.01.2024 | 500 | 50 |
| 1 | 03.01.2024 | 300 | 0 |
| 1 | 04.01.2024 | -700 | 0 |
| 1 | 05.01.2024 | -50 | 0 |
| 1 | 06.01.2024 | 50 | 20 |
| 1 | 07.01.2024 | -30 | 0 |
| 1 | 08.01.2024 | 100 | 100 |

Comment: Спасибо большое! То, что нужно 